# Pandas groupby a column and check multiple conditions to create a new categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Similar to what I had a query about, I am trying to groupby a particular admitting grouper code and this time also check other multiple conditions before setting the category.

For instance, I have the following data frame:

| MemberID | AdmittingCode | LOS | Episode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | a | 10 | 6 |
| 1 | b | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 6 |

And now, instead of simply just checking for the mean and setting categories I want to check whether the mean is 2 times the median, as well as the minimum episode count, is less than 5. By this I mean:

For *AdmittingCode* **a**, the mean is 7.5 ( (5 + 10) / 2 ). Initially, the logic was to set Category for *MemberID* **1** with *AdmittingCode* as  **a**, 0 since it is less than 7.5 LOS (being only 5) and for *MemberID* **2** with *AdmittingCode* as **a**, 1 because it is more than 7.5 LOS (being 10) using the following code:

```
m = df.groupby('AdmittingCode')['LOS'].transform('mean').lt(df['LOS'])
df['LOSCategory'] = m.astype(int)
```

But, now I would like to check 2 more conditions before setting the category column.

1. I would like to check whether the mean is **not** 2 times the median
2. I would also like to check whether the Episode count is less than 5

If **both the above conditions meet** I would want the category to be set as 0 or else 1 (even for cases where only 1 above condition meet but not the other).

Note: Here, the mean and the median is based on per *AdmittingCode*, so **a** would have a different mean to that of **b** like the previous query.

With this logic, for *AdmittingCode* **a** the mean would be 7.5 and the median too 7.5 and for *MemberID* **1** with *AdmittingCode* **a** with *LOS* **5** and *Episode* count **3**, the category would be set to 0. Here, the mean is not 2 times the median, as well as the count, is less than 5.

Finally, the following data frame is observed:

| MemberID | AdmittingCode | LOS | Episode | LOSCategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | a | 10 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 6 | 1 |

Comment: Sorry but your conditions are unclear :/

Comment: Hey @mozway so basically I want to check whether the mean is 2 times the median or not for a particular admitting code. For instance, for the AdmittingCode 'a' there are 2 members, memberID 1 and memberID 2. Here, the LOS is 5 and 10 respectively.  So, the mean is 5 + 10 / 2, i.e. 7.5 and the median is also, 5 + 10 /2 which is 7.5. Now, for the AdmittingCode 'a', the mean is not 2 times the median. Both are equal to 7.5. So, it meets the first condition. Now, for MemberID 1, the Episode count is 3 which is less than 5 so, the flag of LOSCategory is set to 0 as both the conditions meet.

Comment: you have 2 values, so the mean is always equal to the median…? So basically your code seems to reduce to "is Episode greater than 5?"

Comment: For this small instance yes @mozway but for a bigger data frame, I would need to check this thing too.

Comment: my advice, simplify your question (remove text, go to the point), update your example to have something more meaningful that covers the different scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> df['LOSCategory'] = (df.groupby("AdmittingCode")
             .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda xx:(x.LOS.mean() >= x.LOS.median()*2) | (xx.Episode >= 5), axis=1))
             .astype(int)
             .to_list()
                        )


>>> df

   MemberID  AdmittingCode  LOS  Episode  LOSCategory
0          1             a    5        3            0
1          2             a   10        6            1
2          1             b    2        3            0
3          2             b    1        6            1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a function `func`  which returns desired result.

```
LOScategory = df.apply(
         lambda row: func(row['MemberID'], row['AdmittingCode'],row['LOS'],row['Episode']),
         axis=1)
df['LOScategory'] = LOScategory
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on the function. What the function should be and how it would take parameters and operate?

Comment: depends on what your LOCcategory depends on. You need to do the calculation for each row and return the value.